# How to use "?" no get Path Rest?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs, path-parameter

I am developing a rest server in java, netbeans.
I have my GET request:

//myip/application/v1/cardapio/id=1

```
@Stateless
@Path("v1/cardapio")
public class CardapioResource {
        @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        @Path("id={id}")
        public String getCardapio(@PathParam("id") int id) {

            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) gson.toJsonTree(ejb.findById(id));
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            obj.add("dados", array);
            return obj.toString();
        }
}
```

It works correctly.

But I want to do differently, as I saw in other examples, I want to mark the beginning of the variables with the "?".

Ex: //myip/application/v1/cardapio/?id=1

```
    @Stateless
    @Path("v1/cardapio")
    public class CardapioResource {
            @GET
            @Produces("application/json")
            @Path("?id={id}")
            public String getCardapio(@PathParam("id") int id) {

                JsonArray array = (JsonArray) gson.toJsonTree(ejb.findById(id));
                JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
                obj.add("dados", array);
                return obj.toString();
            }
    }
```

Thus error 404, page not found.

Comment: *But I want to do differently, as I saw in other examples, I want to mark the beginning of the variables* you just saw normal usage of query params. It is not part of controller routing. IMHO `@Path("id={id}")` is not what you want. You jsut want to map to `/` and get `@QueryParam`

Comment: @Antoniossss But there is a way to do it, I've seen several cases. I just believe I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: Yes, you are trying to misuse url construct. You want (for whatever reasons) query string to be part of path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seen in "other examples" is just normal usage of URL's query part. Just use it with `@Queryparam`

```
   @Stateless
    @Path("v1/cardapio")
    public class CardapioResource {
            @GET
            @Produces("application/json")
            @Path("/") // can be removed actually
            public String getCardapio(@QueryParam("id") int id) {

                JsonArray array = (JsonArray) gson.toJsonTree(ejb.findById(id));
                JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
                obj.add("dados", array);
                return obj.toString();
            }
    }
```

Here you are mapping `getCardapio` to `v1/cardapio/` and you will try to get `id` from query string so

`Ex: //myip/application/v1/cardapio/?id=1`

will just work.

Comment: One more thing ... how do you get two parameters? Ex: //myip/application/v1/cardapio/?id=1&key=2

Comment: the same way. 2x QueryParam

Answer (score 1):

You can't, after ? sign it's query parameters and not path parameters

You can use `@QueryParam("id")`

Comment: I do not understand very well. Are two types of parameters? I don't know where these signature parameters are.

Comment: @JúlioCésarBindandi use instead of @PathParam("id")

Answer (score 0):

You can also use
`@RequestParam("id") int id`